# Schengen air travel confirmation and private aircraft

Tags: schengen, aircraft, eu-citizens, russian-citizens

One of the requirements for the Schengen visa is for the applicant to present confirmed travel arrangements, most commonly air travel.  This is usually done by booking a ticket and printing out the confirmation.

On this occasion however, the 'host' owns a Gulfstream G650 and wants to pick up his guest in [Perm](http://www.gorodperm.ru/en/) and return with her to Rome.  After a proper visit in Rome, he intends to return to Perm where she will alight.  What should he provide the applicant with in order to meet the Schengen requirement?  Neither host nor guest has done this before so there's no experience to rely upon.

Yes, it's possible to purchase tickets from a commercial airline and then to abandon them once the visa has been issued, and this option has been discussed and summarily discarded as a 'waste of money'.

It's also possible to use Acrobat or Photoshop to mock up a confirmation, but this idea has also been discarded as 'tawdry'.

The host could also send his flight plan that he will file, but this will be in the future and it's indefinite (especially the return trip).  Also, he could send a copy of the registration papers, but this would not indicate anything other than ownership.

She cannot simply write "arrangements have been made" because they would need to see something.  The form says "*State who and how and present corresponding
 documentation*", but nothing more informative is given about the documentation.  What should the applicant enclose with her Schengen application that will demonstrate her capacity to travel when a conventional air confirmation is not appropriate?

The first option is being held in reserve as a last resort.

Comment: What's wrong with simply providing a letter from the host stating that he will pick you up in his private jet on date X and return you on date Y (which are 89 or 90 days apart)? You can always make it a shorter visit, but I suspect you'll at least have to have your entry date firmed up before applying for the visa.

Comment: If you buy refundable tickets then no money is wasted, just a little bit of time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The host would also need to show proof of ownership of the aircraft, but that's easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirement to present anything about travel arrangement derives from article 14(1)(c) of the [regulation](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810). What it says is (my emphasis):

> 1. When applying for a uniform visa, the applicant shall present:
>
> (a) documents indicating the purpose of the journey;
>
> (b) documents in relation to accommodation, or proof of sufficient means to cover his accommodation;
>
> (c) documents indicating that the applicant possesses sufficient **means of subsistence** both for the duration of the intended stay and **for the return to his country of origin or residence**, or for the transit to a third country into which he is certain to be admitted, or that he is in a position to acquire such means lawfully, in accordance with Article 5(1)(c) and (3) of the Schengen Borders Code;
>
> (d) information enabling an assessment of the applicant’s intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for.

Item 35 on the form reads:

> 35. Who is **paying for your cost** of travelling and for your costs of living during your stay? Myself Host person/s Host company. (State who and how and present corresponding
>     documentation)

The fact that “travelling” and “living during your stay“ are mentioned in the same sentence further confirms that this item refers to the requirement laid out in article 14(1)(c) and that what's required is not an actual ticket but only having enough money to buy one.

The only place in the regulation where “reservation of or return or round ticket“ are mentioned is Annex II but it is a “non-exhaustive” list starting with the following sentence “The supporting documents referred to in Article 14, to be submitted by visa applicants **may include** the following:”.

It's true some unofficial documentation implies that you should present a ticket and not having one would be somewhat unusual and might invite scrutiny but it's not *required* as such, only having the means to travel is. Owning a private plane would seem to fulfil that requirement.

Incidentally, in another context (namely seafarer's visas issued at the border, in annex IX), a car registration number is also mentioned as valid information on the “means of transportation”. Obviously, most visitors are not expected to travel by private plane but when travelling by car, proof of ownership would therefore seem to be enough.

Comment: Regarding the ticket part - normal support documentation does not require a _ticket_, but rather a _reservation_ (which can be released after you have applied).